# Button press not logging anything AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue when pressing button "Create Score" the plan is for this to add into a MySQL database, however I'm new to AngularJS and can't seem to get the button click to register -- nothing appears within the console.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Html Code:

```
  <div ng-app="addScores" ng-controller="add_new_score">
      <label>Match_ID:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="match_ID" required>

      <label>Home_Score:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="Home_Score" required>

      <label>Away_Score:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="Away_Score" required>

      <button ng-click="create_score()">Create score</button>

  </div>

  <script>
    var scoreApp = angular.module('addScores', []);

   scoreApp.controller('add_new_score', function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.create_score = function () {
           console.log("logged");

           var scoreData = new scoreObj($scope.match_ID, $scope.Home_Score, $scope.Away_Score);
           $http(
               {
                   method: 'POST',
                   url: "/addScore",
                   data: scoreData
               }
           ).then(function successCallback(response) {
                   alert("Success");
               }, function errorCallback(response) {
                   alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
               }
           )
       };


       function scoreObj(match_ID, Home_Score, Away_Score) {
           this.match_ID = Match_ID;
           this.Home_Score = Home_Score;
           this.Away_Score = Away_Score;
       }
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the angular.js reference in the page?

Your code works just fine

```js
var scoreApp = angular.module('addScores', []);

   scoreApp.controller('add_new_score', function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.create_score = function () {
           console.log("It works");

           var scoreData = new scoreObj($scope.match_ID, $scope.Home_Score, $scope.Away_Score);
           
       };


       function scoreObj(match_ID, Home_Score, Away_Score) {
           this.match_ID = match_ID;
           this.Home_Score = Home_Score;
           this.Away_Score = Away_Score;
       }
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="addScores" ng-controller="add_new_score">
      <label>Match_ID:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="match_ID" required>

      <label>Home_Score:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="Home_Score" required>

      <label>Away_Score:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="Away_Score" required>

      <button ng-click="create_score()">Create score</button>

  </div>
```

Comment: Yes I've added in the angular.js, not even getting the console.log logging the click

Comment: @LThompson do you have the closing script-tag at the end of the angularjs app and controller definition?